# Indicating a range for the Y axis in a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

For my data the average normally lies between 8,000 and 10,000  and I want to indicate this range on my bar chart below,
I want to show to red lines from y=10,000 and y=8,000 and potentially shade the area in between them, if possible.
[Bar chart attachted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ll76.png)

```
Monthly_accidents2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Month,y=Traffic_Accidents))+
  geom_bar(stat ="identity",fill = "#97B3C6")+
  geom_text(aes(label = Traffic_Accidents), vjust = 0.5, colour = "white")+
  ylim(0,12000)+
  #coord_flip()+
  theme_dark()+
  labs(x=NULL,
       y="Number of traffic accidents",
       title = "                                 Traffic Accidents throughout the year")
```

Thanks for any possible help in advance.

I tried creating a data set and adding the two lines but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding the two lines, 'geom_hline' makes it very straightforward. And for the shaded area, you can use 'geom_rect', though I'm guessing your 'Month' variable is factor so it requires a little bit of faffing to convert it to numeric first then adjust so the shaded area covers all of your bars :)

You didn't provide any sample data so I haven't run this but it should work.

```
Monthly_accidents2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Month,y=Traffic_Accidents))+
  geom_bar(stat ="identity",fill = "#97B3C6")+
  geom_text(aes(label = Traffic_Accidents), vjust = 0.5, colour = "white")+
  ylim(0,12000)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(8000, 10000), colour = 'red')+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = min(as.integer(Monthly_accidents2$Month)) - 0.5,
                xmax = max(as.integer(Monthly_accidents2$Month)) + 0.5,
                ymin = 8000, ymax = 10000), alpha = 0.2, fill = 'darkred')+
  #coord_flip()+
  theme_dark()+
  labs(x=NULL,
       y="Number of traffic accidents",
       title = "                                 Traffic Accidents throughout the year")
```

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use `geom_hline` to add some horizontal lines and `annotate` to add a shaded rectangle:

Using some fake example data:

```r
Monthly_accidents2 <- data.frame(
  Month = factor(month.abb, month.abb),
  Traffic_Accidents = 1000 * seq_len(12)
)

library(ggplot2)

base <- ggplot(Monthly_accidents2, aes(x = Month, y = Traffic_Accidents)) +
  geom_col(fill = "#97B3C6") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Traffic_Accidents), vjust = 0.5, colour = "white") +
  ylim(0, 12000) +
  theme_dark() +
  labs(
    x = NULL,
    y = "Number of traffic accidents",
    title = "Traffic Accidents throughout the year"
  ) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5))

base +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(8000, 10000), color = "red") +
  annotate(geom = "rect", ymin = 8000, ymax = 10000, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, fill = "red", alpha = .2)
```

[image]

Comment: BTW: Forgot to note that I added a `theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5))` to center the plot title. Not necessary to do this via spaces. (;

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your plot:

```
    +
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = c(8000, 10000), color = "red"))
```

For the lines

edit:
See stefan's more complete answer.